# How to add ? which extends some class in List

Tags: java, list, generics, collections, java-8

I am having problems with an issue.
Below I am pasting some sample code.

My DefinedAddress class will fetch the address from DB.

```
@Autowired
DBConnection connection;

public class DefinedAddress {

    public String getAddress() {

        List<? extends Address> addressList =connection.getAddresss("SELECT address FROM Address WHERE Id = 1;")

        return  addressList.get(0).location);
    }
}
```

I am creating Junit of this class and have the main logic as below:
I am going to mock database call method connection.getAddresss and will return a list which is having one Address .

```
public class DefinedAddressTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a list 
        List<? extends Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        City city = new City();
        city.setLocation("CurrentLocation");
        addressList.add(city);//Compile time issue 
        //mock Defined Addrss getAddress() method to fetch the address
        Mockit.when(connection.getAddresss("Query").return(addressList );
    }
}
```

Now I know the addressList will not allow to add city as it has ? extends Address and we are not sure which object it is going to add (fair enough)

error is as : The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Address) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (City)

So how can I mock the call and can create my Junit test in that case?

Comment: Well, create a List<Address>.

Comment: If I return an List<Address> in my Junit, Will it be properly mocked?

Comment: The best way to find out is to test it

Comment: There is no way for Mockito to distinguish between a `List<Address>` and a `List<? extends Address>`, because they are identical at runtime; and it would be acceptable at compile time because all `List<Address>`s are instances of `List<? extends Address>`. So yes, `List<Address>` would work.

Answer (score 0):

Create and return a List. A List is also a List and you don't need a subtype of Address for your test case, since you are accessing only a field of Address.